# Is this soft question acceptable?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, on-topic

**Edited version**: What are great examples of comprehensively archived mathematical correspondence (including both handwritten and electronic items)?

Previous version : <s>How should mathematicians archive their work-related output?</s>

Context: here I'm thinking about drafts, and correspondence between mathematicians, either in the form of handwritten material or of emails. For example, I would find it fascinating to read, say, the collection of Letters that Deligne sent to lots of people over the years (and the replies) [1], or the email exchanges  between Green and Tao culminating in their theorem on primes in arithmetic progression.

[1] Some have been archived at IAS https://publications.ias.edu/book/export/html/2582 but they are missing lots of others like a letter to Cvitanovic https://birdtracks.eu/extras/Deligne96.pdf or those to Bar-Natan [https://www.math.toronto.edu/~drorbn/Deligne/](https://www.math.toronto.edu/%7Edrorbn/Deligne/)

Comment: Maybe "How *should* ..."  is a bit too opinion-based(?) -- What about asking instead for examples of how people are actually doing it?

Comment: Thanks, I have edited the question accordingly. Is that suitable?

Comment: To me, that seems o.k. -- but the final decision is to be made by the community.

Comment: I have interpreted the upvotes as a lukewarm go-ahead, so I have posted the question (with a different context to stres the usefulness of email archives) https://mathoverflow.net/questions/416030/archiving-mathematical-correspondence

Comment: I thought that maybe ([tag:online-resources]) would be a suitable tag for the question posted on main. (OTOH maybe it might cause impressions that the questions asks *only* about stuff available online.) On an unrelated note, have you considered adding link also into the post - rather than just in a comment?

Comment: “Comprehensive archiving” is not a practical option anymore — eg do you have an archive of all your MO posts? So the great historical examples, great in part because someone else spent time archiving these mathematicians’ correspondence, leave a lot unanswered about what mathematicians should do now.